# Copying data between two databases ASP.NET CORE WEB API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a problem copying data between two databases. Trying to retrieve data from an existing database using the already written SQL and write the query result to the target database.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use `SqlBulkCopy` to copy data from one database to another:

```
 public IActionResult Test()
    {
        string SourceConnection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=DemoTest;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0";

        // create the destination db
        string DestinationConnection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=TestDemo;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0";

        // define the table to copy
        string TableNameWithSchema = "dbo.Business";

        // define the columsn on the table
        List<string> columns = new List<string>() { "Id", "Name" };
        CopyTable(SourceConnection, DestinationConnection, TableNameWithSchema, columns.ToArray());

        //... other logic
    }

    private static void CopyTable(string sourceConnection,string destinationConnection,string tableNameWithSchema,string[] columns)
    {
        // create options
        SqlBulkCopyOptions o = SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default;
        o = o | SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity;
        o = o | SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls;
        o = o | SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock;

        // Setup a bcp object
        using (SqlBulkCopy bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection, o))
        {
            bcp.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
            bcp.BatchSize = 20000;
            bcp.DestinationTableName = tableNameWithSchema;

            // Iterate the columns
            foreach (string c in columns)
            {
                SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping m = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping();
                m.DestinationColumn = c;
                m.SourceColumn = c;
                bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(m);
            }

            // open source
            using (SqlConnection sourceConn = new SqlConnection(sourceConnection))
            {
                sourceConn.Open();

                // create a command object
                using (SqlCommand sourceComm = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    sourceComm.CommandTimeout = 100;
                    sourceComm.Connection = sourceConn;
                    sourceComm.Parameters.Clear();
                    sourceComm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + tableNameWithSchema;
                    sourceComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    // execute
                    using (SqlDataReader Reader = sourceComm.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        // this is where the data is moved!
                        bcp.WriteToServer(Reader);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Reference:

https://mikesdotnet.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/using-sqlbulkcopy-to-copy-data-from-one-database-to-another-2/

Answer (score 0):

While looping though the DataReader, you need to build your insert statements and then execute in different Database.

Comment: So far I've tried to do this on DbContext. I have no idea how to do this on DataReader